# Default property value of a component

Tags: delphi, properties, components, delphi-7

I wonder if it is possible to define a default property value to a component. 
In another words, I want to set, in design time, an unique name (maybe GUID) to each TDBGrid in the system, is it possible? 
 There is another way to control uniqueness of a component that works both in runtime and design time. Also it must persists after I close delphi; e.g combobox list values.

Thanks in advance!

### edit

below is the code, that is not working:

```
type
  TMDBGrid = class(TDBGrid)
  private
    FUniqueName: String;
  protected
    function DefaultUniqueName: String;
    function GetUniqueName: String;
    procedure SetUniqueName(const AName: String);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property UniqueName: String read GetUniqueName write SetUniqueName;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses uComponentUtils;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MLStandard', [TMDBGrid]);
end;

{ TMDBGrid }

constructor TMDBGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FUniqueName := DefaultUniqueName;
end;

function TMDBGrid.DefaultUniqueName: String;
begin
  Result := GenerateGUID(True);
end;

function TMDBGrid.GetUniqueName: String;
begin
  Result := '';
end;

procedure TMDBGrid.SetUniqueName(const AName: String);
begin
  FUniqueName := AName;
  if FUniqueName = '' then
    FUniqueName := DefaultUniqueName;
end;

function GenerateGUID(PlainText: Boolean = False): String;
var G: TGUID;
begin
  CreateGUID(G);
  Result:= GUIDToString(G);
  if PlainText then
    Result := MultiStringReplace(Result, ['{','}','[',']','-','.',' ','(',')'],
                                         ['','','','','','','','',''],
                                         [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
end;
```

**"It's not working"** means when a TDBGrid is added to any form, UNIQUENAME is empty. It should have a GUID.

Comment: You can add a property to a component and give it a value on creation that is then persisted to and from the .dfm file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my code should work?

Comment: Hard to see how that would fail. It will persist to the .dfm file. Obviously it's not going to get the job done for controls that are created at run time. It also cannot work if you create multiple instances of the same form. You'll have controls on different forms with the same ID. Or is that what you want? Anyway, let's be clear. What do you mean exactly by "not working"?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan nevermind, "Obviously it's not going to get the job done for controls that are created at run time. "

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the final component should work like this: everytime another component is added to a form, a new uniquename is generated.

Comment: So please do tell us exactly how it fails. And do we need to know anything about `DefaultUniqueName`?

Comment: I don't understand how combo-box list values are an example of a way to control uniqueness of a component.

Comment: @RobKennedy I meant that the combo-box list values ​​remain intact even with Delphi closed, because it is persisted to and from .dfm file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `GetUniqueName` does not return anything. It needs to return `FUniqueName`.

```
function TMDBGrid.GetUniqueName: String;
begin
  Result := FUniqueName;
end;
```

Or you could delete the getter and change the property to be like so:

```
property UniqueName: String read FUniqueName write SetUniqueName;
```

Comment: I just don't believe I did this! Super FacePalm!

Comment: Actually the big lesson here is how important it is to cut code down to a minimal reproduction. There's extraneous code even in the small amount that you posted. Once you have a minimal reproduction, it's easy to find the problem because there is simply less code to look at. And when asking a question, a good minimal reproduction makes our lives easier, and means you'll have a better and cleaner question.

Comment: This property will be overriden in runtime? shouldn't I add   if csDesigning in ComponentState then

Comment: No, because it will be read from the .dfm file. The first time you drop the component on the form, there are no .dfm values to read so you get the default, which is what you set in the constructor.

Comment: +1 Good to now it will not be overwritten at runtime. I did'nt know that !

Comment: Unless the property has a `default` value and that value is set. For example `property MyProp: Integer read FMyProp write SetMyProp default 0;` If the value of this property is `0` (the default), then it won't even save it in the DFM.